# curs.execute throwing invalid length specified for statement

Tags: python

Could be something simple that I am struck with,

Code below throws the error in python 3.6:

```
curs.execute (sql_command)
cx_oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24373: invalid length specified for statement.
```

Code:

```
import cx_oracle
conn = cx_oracle.connect(xx/xx@xx)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.arraysize=100
f = open('C:/query.sql')
file_read = f.read()
f.close()
sql_split = file_read.split(';')
for sql_command in sql_split:
    curs.execute (sql_command)
results = curs.fetchall()
for row in results:
    print(''.join(row))
curs.close
conn.close
```

Comment: As a first debugging step, print each command before you execute it.

Comment: Also, you want `curse.close()` instead of `curs.close`, and the same with `conn`.

Comment: We're going to need to see what SQL statement, from the file you are loading, is causing the error.